# How to group arraylist objects by attribute?

Tags: java

```
    HurT Hurricane_ArrL = new HurT(String category, int number);
    ArrayList<HurT> Hurricane_ArrL = new ArrayList<HurT>();
    Hurricane_ArrL.add(new HurT("Category1", 0));
```

I'm trying to figure out how to group objects by attributes but I'm getting the errors:

```
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- Syntax error on token "category", delete this 
 token
- String cannot be resolved to a variable
- number cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: When you are calling a method, you can't put the String and int. The line should be ``HurT Hurrican_Arrl = new HurT(category, number);``

Comment: delete the first line shown here

Comment: The compiler is telling you that this is a syntax error. You're trying to declare a new HurT object and ur defining parameters instead of assigning values. First line looks more like a constructor declaration than an object instationation.

Comment: When I do, I get the error: The method add(int, HurricaneTesterV1) in the type ArrayList<HurricaneTesterV1> is not applicable for the 
 arguments (String, int)

Comment: Like mentioned earlier, delete the first line of code. The other two should be fine as they are.

Comment: `HurricaneTesterV1` and a `add` with 2 parameters doesn't appear in your code. You are giving errors of code that we don't see

Comment: Share the `HurT` class code

Comment: You can only use a constructor if this type of constructor is declared in your class

Answer (score 1):

The code should be modified as below :

while creating the instance, In the below case you are invoking parameterized constructor, where you just need to pass the values, but not with Data Type.

```
HurT Hurricane_ArrL = new HurT(category,number);
ArrayList<HurT> Hurricane_ArrL = new ArrayList<HurT>();
Hurricane_ArrL.add(new HurT("Category1", 0));
```

the above one would resolve your issue.

Comment: I get: The constructor HurricaneTesterV1(String, int) is undefined

Comment: it means you have not defined parameterized constructor in your class.